# Tuplas a DataFrame (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Muy buenas compañeros, tengo esta duda que me tiene días investigando una solución....
Miren:

```
import pandas as pd
Capital=['Tokio','Madrid','Lima']#Listas random
Habitantes=[35,45,10]
Continente=['Sur America','Europa','Asia']
ejemplo={'Paises':Capital,
      'Habitantes':Habitantes,
      'Continente':Continente}
serie= pd.DataFrame(ejemplo)#proceso a dataFrame
print(serie)
#Ingrese por teclado nuevos valores
pais1=input("Ingrese un pais: ")
habi1=input("Ingrese habitantes: ")
conti1=input("Ingrese un continente: ")
Capital.append(pais1)
Habitantes.append(habi1)
Continente.append(conti1)
print(serie)
```

por algún motivo no agrega lo que ingrese en la última parte.... me presenta esto:
[image: out>>]

Disculpen si se ve muy "novato" mi código, estoy empezando y bueno espero encontrar una solución... Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que debes crear un nuevo registro de la forma que creaste la estructura de datos inicial con el que inicializas el DataFrame, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
# import pandas as pd
Capital=['Tokio','Madrid','Lima']#Listas random
Habitantes=[35,45,10]
Continente=['Sur America','Europa','Asia']
ejemplo={'Paises':Capital,
         'Habitantes':Habitantes,
         'Continente':Continente}

df = pd.DataFrame(ejemplo)

pais1=input("Ingrese un pais: ")
habi1=input("Ingrese habitantes: ")
conti1=input("Ingrese un continente: ")

nueva_row = {'Paises':pais1, 'Habitantes':habi1, 'Continente':conti1}

df = df.append(nueva_row, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: Vaya amigo, muchas gracias. Funciona a la perfección... podré dormir tranquilo esta noche..

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
Capital=['Tokio','Madrid','Lima']#Listas random
Habitantes=[35,45,10]
Continente=['Sur America','Europa','Asia']


#Ingrese por teclado nuevos valores
pais1=input("Ingrese un pais: ")
habi1=input("Ingrese habitantes: ")
conti1=input("Ingrese un continente: ")
Capital.append(pais1)
Habitantes.append(habi1)
Continente.append(conti1)
ejemplo={'Paises':Capital,
      'Habitantes':Habitantes,
      'Continente':Continente}
serie= pd.DataFrame(ejemplo)
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]print(serie)
```

###Lo que pasaba es que el data frame no contenía los valores nuevos que escribes ##en el input. Lo que tienes que hacer es crear el data frame después de agregar ##los valores nuevos.

##What happened is that the data frame did not contain the new values that you ##write in the input. What you have to do is create the data frame after adding ##the new values.

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta de algo tan obvio jaja. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que cuando haces esos nuevos `.append()` a tus arreglos, estas actualizando esos arreglos, mas no tu DataFrame que asignaste a la variable `ejemplo`. Esa variable se quedó con lo último que le asignaste, que eran tus arreglos sin esos nuevos valores.

Lo que necesitas es actualizar tus datos en la variable `ejemplo`. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer es reasignar tu variable con un nuevo objeto `DataFrame` en cada actualización, así:

```py
pais1 = input("Ingrese un pais: ")
habi1 = input("Ingrese habitantes: ")
conti1 = input("Ingrese un continente: ")
Capital.append(pais1)
Habitantes.append(habi1)
Continente.append(conti1)
ejemplo = {
  'Paises': Capital,
  'Habitantes': Habitantes,
  'Continente': Continente
}
df = pd.DataFrame(ejemplo) # Aquí ya tendrás los datos actualizados
```

Comment: Si me lo agrega, pero pierde el formato del pandas.... osea ya no me muestra filas y columnas